# Normal bundle of the two-dimensional sphere manifold embedded in $\mathbb R^4$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $M \subset \mathbb R^4$ be a smooth manifold diffeomorphic to $S^2$. How can one prove that normal bundle of $M$ has at least one non-vanishing global section. I think that $M$ should be parametrizable and hence has one non-vanishing global section, however I can not prove rigorously that $M$ is parametrizable.

Answer (score 1):

Since $M$ is simply-connected, its normal bundle $\nu$ in $R^4$ has to be orientable. Thus, to show its triviality, it suffices to show that $e(\nu)=0$. Since $e(\nu)$ is the self-intersection number of $M$ in $R^4$, it is zero. Hence, $\nu$ is trivial.

Comment: But why is this self-intersection zero?

Comment: @se0808: any compact surfaces $M$ in $\mathbb R^4$ has zero intersection as you can move one surface far enough by a translation $M + p$ so that $M$ and $M+p$ has no intersection.

Comment: @se0808: You can also say that the intersection number of a null-homologous cycle with any other cycle is zero.